# Load JSON from Internal File HTML

Tags: html, json, file

Instead of fetching another file to load JSON data (local or remote), is it possible to just import the data into the HTML class?

The reason why I am asking this is because I would like to create 1 file that contains the HTML, CSS, JQuery, and JSON data without the browser having to fetch any other files.

Ideas?

Comment: <script></script>  ...  you will still need to load the jquery library

Comment: So what I did was copy the entire contents of jquery.js into the head of the HTML file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply put the data in a normal Javascript variable using an object literal.

```
var myData = { ... };
```

Comment: But if you do this, could you access this JavaScript data from JQuery?

Comment: @JakeChasan: Yes; Javascript code can read Javascript variables.